# Edit Control is not updated using C# custom action in WIX

Tags: c#, installation, wix, custom-action, wix3.11

I have a custom UI with an `Edit` control on it, and I want to update it with a c# custom action that is called on a button click.

This is a test WIX fragment I created to demonstrate you the problem, it contains the UI and custom actions declarations.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <UI>
      <Dialog Id="TestDlg" Width="370" Height="270">
        <Control Id="TextBox" Type="Edit" X="80" Y="117" Height="17" Width="250"  Property="EDITBOXVALUE" Text="[EDITBOXVALUE]"/>
        <Control Id="Button" Type="PushButton" X="331" Y="117" Height="16" Width="17" Text="Update">
          <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="UpdateEditBox" Order="1">1</Publish>

          <!-- This is a workaround to update property I found here https://legalizeadulthood.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/ui-custom-action-guidelines/ -->
          <Publish Property="EDITBOXVALUE" Value="[EDITBOXVALUE]" Order="2">1</Publish>
        </Control>
      </Dialog>
    </UI>
    <Binary Id="ServerActions" SourceFile="$(var.CustomActions.TargetDir)$(var.CustomActions.TargetName).CA.dll" />
    <CustomAction Id="UpdateEditBox" BinaryKey="ServerActions" DllEntry="UpdateEditBox" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

This is c# custom action:

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult UpdateEditBox(Session session)
{
    session ["EDITBOXVALUE"] = "Updated Value";
    return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

Now here is the problem I experience, if I just simply click on the button the edit box is updated, BUT, if I first put some text to the edit box an THEN click the button the edit box is no longer updated.

I examined the installation logs (by running the installer with this command `msiexec.exe /i MyInstaller.msi /l*vx Output.txt`), and here is what I found:

```
MSI (c) (FC!24) [17:13:41:225]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding EDITBOXVALUE property. Its value is 'Updated Value'.
MSI (c) (FC:44) [17:13:41:236]: Closing MSIHANDLE (1) of type 790542 for thread 9980
Action ended 17:13:41: UpdateEditBox. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (FC:FC) [17:13:44:521]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying EDITBOXVALUE property. Its current value is 'Updated Value'. Its new value: 'NEW VALUE I TYPED INTO EDIT BOX'.
MSI (c) (FC:FC) [17:13:44:633]: Doing action: UpdateEditBox
Action 17:13:44: UpdateEditBox. 
Action start 17:13:44: UpdateEditBox.
MSI (c) (FC:FC) [17:13:44:635]: Creating MSIHANDLE (5) of type 790542 for thread 9980
MSI (c) (FC:6C) [17:13:44:635]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\MYKHAI~1.SEN\AppData\Local\Temp\MSIAAE1.tmp, Entrypoint: UpdateEditBox
MSI (c) (FC!A0) [17:13:44:666]: Creating MSIHANDLE (6) of type 790531 for thread 27552
MSI (c) (FC!A0) [17:13:44:666]: Closing MSIHANDLE (6) of type 790531 for thread 27552
MSI (c) (FC!A0) [17:13:44:710]: Creating MSIHANDLE (7) of type 790531 for thread 27552
MSI (c) (FC!A0) [17:13:44:710]: Closing MSIHANDLE (7) of type 790531 for thread 27552
MSI (c) (FC!A0) [17:13:44:745]: Creating MSIHANDLE (8) of type 790531 for thread 27552
MSI (c) (FC!A0) [17:13:44:748]: Closing MSIHANDLE (8) of type 790531 for thread 27552
MSI (c) (FC!A0) [17:13:49:399]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying EDITBOXVALUE property. Its current value is 'NEW VALUE I TYPED INTO EDIT BOX'. Its new value: 'Updated Value'.
MSI (c) (FC:6C) [17:13:49:425]: Closing MSIHANDLE (5) of type 790542 for thread 9980
Action ended 17:13:49: UpdateEditBox. Return value 1.
Action 17:13:52: CancelDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 17:13:53: WelcomeDlg. Return value 2.
```

Based on this log it seems the property was updated, nevertheless it was not reflected on the UI.

Does anyone know what's going on here, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little trick I've come up with to overcome this problem, not very elegant, but it works nevertheless.

The main idea is that you have a precise copy of your main dialog and whenever you want to update the UI, when the property changes, you just switch between these two copies. From the example in the question, it would like something like this:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <UI>
      <Dialog Id="TestDlg" Width="370" Height="270">
        <Control Id="TextBox" Type="Edit" X="80" Y="117" Height="17" Width="250"  Property="EDITBOXVALUE" Text="[EDITBOXVALUE]"/>
        <Control Id="Button" Type="PushButton" X="331" Y="117" Height="16" Width="17" Text="Update">
          <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="UpdateEditBox" Order="1">1</Publish>
        </Control>
      </Dialog>
    </UI>
    <UI>
      <Dialog Id="TestCopyDlg" Width="370" Height="270">
        <Control Id="TextBox" Type="Edit" X="80" Y="117" Height="17" Width="250"  Property="EDITBOXVALUE" Text="[EDITBOXVALUE]"/>
        <Control Id="Button" Type="PushButton" X="331" Y="117" Height="16" Width="17" Text="Update">
          <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="UpdateEditBox" Order="1">1</Publish>
        </Control>
      </Dialog>
    </UI>
    <Binary Id="ServerActions" SourceFile="$(var.CustomActions.TargetDir)$(var.CustomActions.TargetName).CA.dll" />
    <CustomAction Id="UpdateEditBox" BinaryKey="ServerActions" DllEntry="UpdateEditBox" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Notice that I'm no longer using this `<Publish Property="EDITBOXVALUE" Value="[EDITBOXVALUE]" Order="2">1</Publish>` because it is no longer needed, because we are switching to another UI.

And then somewhere in your UI sequence you would have:

```
  <Publish Dialog="TestDlg" Control="Button" Event="NewDialog" Value="TestCopyDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="TestCopyDlg" Control="Button" Event="NewDialog" Value="TestDlg">1</Publish>
```